# Were there time just after the Big Bang?

Tags: big-bang

I have understood that just after the Big Bang there were no cesium atoms and the definition of time requires cesium atoms. So were there any time before cesium atoms appeared in the universe?.

Comment: Did space exist before rulers were invented?

Comment: There is a very distinct difference between the (human) **definition** of a concept and its **existence**. And **measurability** is different *again*. It's important not to get these terms mixed up. The usual statement is that time came into **existence** at the instant of the Big Bang, it was immediately **measurable** but it was only **defined** by humans much much much later. Cesium atoms come into play as a way of defining a unit of time (a commonly known quantity of time in terms of which measurements can be expressed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of time **does not** require cesium atoms!

The first atoms to appear were hydrogen atoms - as the initial expansion occurred. Helium came next, and cesium was much later, once we had stars to produce heavier atoms.

Time certainly passed - billions of years.

Perhaps you are thinking of the fact that humans may use cesium as a benchmark for measuring time. Remember, just because we weren't measuring time back then (or even existing...) it still passed by without us.

Comment: So in the beginning, there were time but it was non-measurable for billions of years and measurable after that?

Comment: Who was around to measure it? Cesium is just how *we* as humans measure time. We still do it based on when the sun rises, or when we complete one revolution about the sun. Measurement is a wholly different thing than existence...